# Source maps in webpack + closure compiler

Tags: webpack, google-closure-compiler, source-maps

I would like to use SourceMaps generated by Closure Compiler using Webpack but I cant figure out how to do it.

Here is my webpack config:

```
const ClosureCompiler = require('google-closure-compiler-js').webpack;

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/build/",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        //sourceMapFilename: "./app.js.map",
    },
    plugins: [
        new ClosureCompiler({
            compiler: {
                language_in: 'ECMASCRIPT5',
                language_out: 'ECMASCRIPT5',
                compilation_level: 'ADVANCED',
                create_source_map: __dirname + './output.js.map'
            },
            concurrency: 3,
        })
    ]
};
```

When I run webpack, nothing happen. Why? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest version of google-closure-compiler-js (`20170910.0.1`), I was able to get it to work using the following options:

```
plugins: [
  new ClosureCompiler({
    options: {
      languageIn: 'ECMASCRIPT6',
      languageOut: 'ECMASCRIPT5',
      compilationLevel: 'ADVANCED',
      createSourceMap: true
    }
  })
]
```